# Class has no instance of setter '_scheduler'

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I have a class which has a ViewChild _scheduler.  Im not really sure why it needs a setter though since i am only wanting to use it to get the markup related to it.  I am having some issues reading the error code since it isnt quite relating back to my files entirely as it is tracing X.template.dart so i cant quite see which line the issues are on.

I was looking at the html file, but it is actually just pointing to the closing tag to the Div.
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a private name for the `ViewChild`. In the generated code it is trying to set the `ViewChild` `_scheduler` on an instance of the component, but since it's private, the setter call is failing. It should work if you rename it to `scheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable in dart that is prefixed with an "_" makes a variable private to that class.

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour (see important concepts bullet 6)

From the perspective of the parent class, the variable does not exist so the error is valid.